# Having trouble with numpy append function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I was doing work for a course today, and the assignment was to create a tic tac toe board. The possibilities method takes a tic tac toe board as an input, and checks if any of the values are "0", meaning that it's an open space. My plan would be to add the location of the 0 to an array, called locations, and then return locations at the end of the function. However, when I try to append the location of the 0 to the locations array, I keep getting this issue: "all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 2 and the array at index 1 has size 1". Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

```
import numpy as np

def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((3,3), dtype = "int")
    return board

def place(board, player, position):
    x, y = position
    board[x][y] = player
 
    
def posibilities(board):
    locations = np.empty(shape=[2,0])
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for x in range(len(board[0])):
            if board[i][x] == 0:
                locations = np.append(locations, [[i,x]], axis=1)
    print(locations)
    
posibilities(create_board())
```

Comment: Use list and list append.  `np.append` is slow and hard to use right.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj suggested use list instead and change it to `np.array` at the end, that is:

```
def posibilities(board):
    locations = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for x in range(len(board[0])):
            if board[i][x] == 0:
                locations.append([[i,x]])
    locations = np.array(locations) # or np.concatenate(locations) depending what you want
    print(locations)
```

This is the proper way to do this due to the fact that python lists are mutable and numpy arrays aren't.

Comment: @TejaKoduru I added np.concatenate(locations) besides np.array(locations) because you may want this instead

Answer (score 0):

```
In [530]: board = np.random.randint(0,2,(3,3))                                                       
In [531]: board                                                                                      
Out[531]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Looks like you are trying to collect the locations on the board where it is 0.  `argwhere` does this nicely:

```
In [532]: np.argwhere(board==0)                                                                      
Out[532]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 2]])
```

With the list append:

```
In [533]: alist = []                                                                                 
In [534]: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     for j in range(3): 
     ...:         if board[i,j]==0: 
     ...:             alist.append([i,j]) 
     ...:                                                                                            
In [535]: alist                                                                                      
Out[535]: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2]]
```

`argwhere` actually uses `np.nonzero` to get a tuple of arrays which index the desired locations.

```
In [536]: np.nonzero(board==0)                                                                       
Out[536]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2]))
```

Often this `nonzero` version is easier to use.  For example it can be used directly to select all those cells:

```
In [537]: board[np.nonzero(board==0)]                                                                
Out[537]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

and setting some of those to 1:

```
In [538]: board[np.nonzero(board==0)] = np.random.randint(0,2,6)                                     
In [539]: board                                                                                      
Out[539]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```